# tailwind bg-opacity-80 not rendering correctly

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am wanting to set a opaque background on element, I want the opaque to be a custom color I have added to my theme in my `tailwind.config.js` however using something like `<div class="bg-purple bg-opacity-80"></div>` just shows a solid purple colour, have I setup my tailwind config incorrectly?

```
 module.exports = {
  future: {
    // removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    // purgeLayersByDefault: true,
  },
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      purple:"#32286A",
      lightPurple: "#9893B4",
      peach: "#FC8370",
      white: "#ffffff",
      transparent: "transparent",
      offWhite: "#F0F0E2",
      pink: "#E63C8C"
    },
    fontFamily: {
      'dmSans': ['DM Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif']
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss-animatecss')({
      //classes: ['animate__animated', 'animate__fadeIn', 'animate__bounce', 'animate__slideInDown', 'animate__slideInUp'],
      settings: {
        animatedSpeed: 1000,
        heartBeatSpeed: 1000,
        hingeSpeed: 2000,
        bounceInSpeed: 750,
        bounceOutSpeed: 750,
        animationDelaySpeed: 1000
      },
      variants: ['responsive', 'hover', 'reduced-motion'],
    })
  ],
}
```

Comment: Which version of tailwind are you using. `bg-opacity-80` was introduced on version 2+.

Comment: doh! That would be why, 1.9.6